# MSSQL C# query Only add row if value is unique

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, upsert

I have a simple c# application that writes to a database using the following.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table WHERE deviceName='deviceNAMEDATA')
    UPDATE HeartBeat
        SET DeviceName = 'DEVICENAMEDATA',
            LastConnect = 'DATETIMEDATA'
ELSE
    INSERT INTO HeartBeat
        VALUES('DeviceNAMEDATA', 'DATETIMEDATA')
```

DEVICENAMEDATA and DATETIMEDATA are replaced using a string builder to the name of the device and the time.

I left it running for an hour and everything seemed to be working i was not getting any duplicate records however after leaving it running for 24 hours the database has about 20 duplicate records.

Is there a better way of ensuring that two rows with the same device name are never created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your update statement - You are updating both columns instead of using the `DeviceName` column in the `Where` clause. It should look like this:

```
UPDATE HeartBeat
SET LastConnect = 'DATETIMEDATA'
WHERE DeviceName = 'DEVICENAMEDATA'
```

That being said, you should probably use the `DeviceName` as the [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) for your table, which will make it impossible for it to have multiple values.

Also, while on the subject of "upsert", you should read Dan Guzman's [blog post](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2007/10/28/Conditional-INSERTUPDATE-Race-Condition.aspx) about how to avoid race condition in "upsert" in SQL Server.

One more thing - you should always specify the columns list in an insert statement.

Here is how I would write this:

```
SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    IF EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table 
    WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
    WHERE deviceName='deviceNAMEDATA'
    ) 

        UPDATE HeartBeat
        SET LastConnect = 'DATETIMEDATA'
        WHERE DeviceName = 'DEVICENAMEDATA'
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO HeartBeat (DeviceName, LastConnect)
        VALUES('DeviceNAMEDATA', 'DATETIMEDATA')

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks thats perfect, I set the primary key to the devicename and used this query within the application after deleting all the duplicates.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of ensuring that two rows with the same device name are never created ?

Yes, have the database ensure the data integrity using a  a unique constraint/index:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_deviceName unique (deviceName);
```

You will need to adapt your code to catch errors on the `insert`.  If this is T-SQL code, you can use a `try`/`catch` block.